# Managing Players on a World Server

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am currently developing the server part of a game (MMORPG) and I am stuck on a point that seems to me quite important: how to manage the packets received by the clients and their logic?

Let me explain: I know how to get a connection from a client, how to store the socket of this client but I don't know how to manage packets that it will send later and apply the modifications on the server (all asynchronously).

I had thought of 2 solutions:
1) As soon as the server detects a client connection, it creates a thread for the client. So there is 1 thread per client that will handle the packets of a single client. But in this case, the more clients there are, the more processor will be called right?

2) As soon as the server detects a new client, it stores it in a list. A thread will loop on the client list and see if the current client is sending a packet. If so, it manages it. But this solution also poses a problem: how to manage this packet? Create a new thread specifically for this packet? But I come back to the starting point: too many packets will overload the machine.

A friend offered me a third solution: make a mixture of both. In this way, a thread would take care of NB_MAX_CLIENT.

I would like to know if there are other ways of doing that.
I'm on Windows. I develop with Visual Studio in C ++ and I use the Winsocks.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I would say make it work for 5 clients and don't worry about any more. You are going to face much bigger problems than having too many threads open. You will be able to come back and make it scale better, but if you get stuck too much on scaling you will possibly never have a project that needs to scale.

Comment: Is latency a problem? If not, you can use MySQL to store the data, and use distributed control to process the information, using multiple virtual machines, as this is something that is getting use on the cloud services, if latency is a problem, then you really need to maximize the resources on a single working server, and distribute the work on the available nodes, using a single server to tell the client where to connect when any of the available working node is "full"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As soon as the server detects a client connection, it creates a thread for the client. So there is 1 thread per client that will handle the packets of a single client. But in this case, the more clients there are, the more processor will be called right?

This is fairly common unless you are running out of RAM from the stacks that each thread requires (typically OS threads require an OS stack per physical thread). The other issue is too many context switches that might make you consider otherwise.

Avoiding the thread issue is really difficult because you lose the ability to do anything per client without pivoting off a data structure since you have no idea what stack will handle the next packet.

> As soon as the server detects a new client, it stores it in a list. A thread will loop on the client list and see if the current client is sending a packet. If so, it manages it. But this solution also poses a problem: how to manage this packet?

Typically you setup a producer consumer set of threads for this. One producer gets each packet and sends it to a queue which is then consumed by some number of worker threads that just handle each item.

Honestly doing this correctly requires a ton of work (as in an example of it was a major piece of technology that Netflix developed) you probably should avoid it to simplify things.

Especially since RAM is cheap and 1MB per thread requires concurrency that will knock you over from other problems before your dedicated thread stacks kill you. (Similarly when context switches become your biggest issue you are pretty far along unless you are doing something unrelated to this discussion wrong).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I understand correctly, I just have to save my packets received in a list and then manage them with a list of threads ?

Comment: @DarkyZShadow: That would work, you would need to figure out a synchronization method for ensuring you don't do unsafe cross thread read and writes but there are a few ways to handle that.